# Why do I have two R file in gen package?

Tags: android

[image: My workspace]

At first the MainActivity.java didn't have an error.
I have configed id for button, text fields. And they are added in com.mikeyaworski.basiccalculations

but i don't know what I have done that the project has two R.java in gen package.

one is in package android.support.v7.appcompat.
other is in com.mikeyaworski.basiccalculations (my config is here).

MainActivity.java has an error because cannot find R.layout.activity_main (because this variable is in com.mikeyaworski.basiccalculations package but i think the project use R.java from package android.support.v7.appcompat)

what should I do for this problem?

Comment: it is normal there are 2 R file

Comment: I think there is different issue in here

Comment: can you write your import on your mainactivity class

Comment: can you post the import statements for your MainActivity. See if you have `import android.R;` If so remove

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean built your project and check proper R file(i.e com.mikeyaworski.basiccalculations.R) is imported, done the trick for me.Hope solve your issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Read this [Managing Projects - Library Projects:](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects)